# Run a SQL query on multiple databases on a single server, single instance

Tags: sql, multiple-databases

I know there are a number of posts regarding the topic but I would like you to provide a solution to run the following (rebuild indexes) query on multiple databases, each with the same structure and hosted in the same instance.

The query is:

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(255)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'base table'

OPEN TableCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
DBCC DBREINDEX(@TableName,' ',90)
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
END

CLOSE TableCursor

DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

I can run this manually and it works but there are 180 databases on this instance.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Assuming you're using SQL Server [sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will rebuild all indexes on all tables for every user database, except for system databases like master, **tempdb**, **model**, and **msdb**. You can modify the WHERE clause in the cursor to exclude additional databases if needed.

Make sure to take database backup make or to test this on a non-production environment first to ensure it does not cause any unexpected issues.

```
DECLARE @dbname NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @sql = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + '; ALTER INDEX ALL ON ALL TABLES REBUILD;'
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```